# How to implement sharing via Twitter, mail & Tumblr using ShareKit

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use ShareKit to implement sharing via Twitter, mail & Tumbler but I am unable to make them work correctly.

I implemented the following code on view load,

```
SHKItem *item;
item=[SHKItem image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"] title:@"Praveen"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Please help me..

Comment: What is your problem? Saying that you are unable to make it work does not really help. Did you read the documentation of ShareKit?

Comment: have you successfully login on any of site?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161454/how-to-implement-sharing-via-twitter-mail-tumblr-using-sharekit

Answer (score 2):

Try these following lines ;) it works for me :)

```
    NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"marriage0.jpg"];
    NSString *message=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.myMessage.text];
    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]; 
    SHKItem *fbItem = [SHKItem image:image title:message]; 
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:fbItem];
```